# Search case insensitive

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search string contain string in field. Like search like in SQL
I tried to use the regex to search.

```
$params["query"]["bool"]["filter"][]["regexp"][$item_key] = '.*'.$search_pattern.'.*'
```

I can only search for lower word. For upper word , it is not working.
Example:

my title is : ABC

if search text is : abc -> has result

if search text is : ABC -> no result

My mapping config is :

```
`'mappings' => [
        'items' => [
            "title" => [
                "type" => "text",
                "fields" => [
                    "keyword" => [
                        "type" => "keyword",
                    ]
                ],
                "fielddata" => true,
                "index" => "not_analyzed",
            ]
        ]
    ]`
```

Does anyone have any idea for search in case insensitive?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using prefix query inside the bool filter. Elasticsearch don't analyze the query for filters. You can move your [regex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) to query context where the query terms will be analyzed by the index analyzer. To make sure terms are same while indexing and searching elastic appiles the same analyzer while searching.

You can apply a [standard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html) analyzer

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "items": {
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    },
                    "fielddata": true,
                    "analyzer": "standard"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Query

```
{
    "query": {
        "regexp":{
            "title": "ab.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried to change the mapping config like you said. But I got this error:
 {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Mapper for [title] conflicts with existing m
  apping in other types:\n[mapper [title] has different [analyzer]]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"
  Mapper for [title] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [title] has different [analyzer]]"},"st
  atus":400}

Comment: Like what I said above. I want to use some feature has similar **like** in SQL .
Say Sample Data in Field : Nervous Nightingale qrBGHaSdMe

Search 
title : Neeraj - no result
title:neeraj - get result
title:ne - get result
title: eraj - get result

Comment: the errror is trying to say you applying these mappings on the same index, why don't you create a fresh index.

Comment: can you please explain your usecase using a psuedo query or example, i am not able to understand your usecase. Maybe i can help better then

Comment: Thank you for reply. 
I have created paste bin for more detail : https://pastebin.com/TnPVCt2B

---
the errror is trying to say you applying these mappings on the same index, why don't you create a fresh inde
---
Did you mean I can't change  in the old mapping.

Comment: thanks i got it, so you have two clauses in search query on is regex and other is menu_id terms field. You can move the regex filter to query so that standard analyzer can work at query time to lowercase the terms and make search case insensitive. I supplied you mappings to define standard analyzer on title field. I will update my post to add menu_id filter

Comment: Thank you I have done it. Create new index and apply the these setting . it worked. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: And I think i don't need to move regex filter to query. I still get the result